# PG query for select and group in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg

I am learning `join` tables for associations and fire `select` and `group` query together. Suppose I have database like:

**Orders:**

```
#has_many :items
id , title , description
```

**Items:**

```
#belongs_to :order
#belongs_to :product
id , order_id , name , product_id , cost
```

Now I want to list all order's title with total number of order_id from Item table.
For eg:

```
Order_title_1 => 5 (count of order_id )
```

I tried this query but gives error: I know it is not correct

```
Item.joins(:orders).select("orders.id, orders.title, SUM(items.order_id) as total").group("order_id")
```

Comment: ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'orders' was not found on Item; perhaps you misspelled it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are in postgresql, columns present in the `SELECT` clause must be present in the *group by* clause, except the one you used inside the *aggregate* function. But in your case, it didn't so. Try to write the code as :

```
Item.joins(:order)
    .select("orders.id, orders.title, SUM(items.order_id) as total")
    .group("orders.id, orders.title")
```

Comment: 2.1.2 :057 > Item.joins(:orders).select("orders.id, orders.title, SUM(items.order_id) as total").group("orders.id, orders.title")
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'orders' was not found on Item; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: @HetalKhunti I did.. ;)

Comment: It works now... I also tried the same but as I commented above I was getting an error but now it works thanks